# Entity framework 6 Concept clear regarding Remove, RemoveRange, EntityState.Deleted

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I use Entity framework 6 in my projects and I always have doubts regarding some of the concepts which are used to delete objects using EF.

I still don't know which one works in which scenario. I just try all and if one works I leave it until the code is working. But no wi need to understand this concept once and for all. I did my research my unable to understand the concept clearly.

I have a domain class in EF which have multiple referencing entities. For example. I have a domain class called **Course** and It has multiple referencing objects mentioned below in the code.

```
public class Course
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

        public virtual PricingSchedule PricingSchedule { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<CustomerCourse> AssignedCustomers { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<License> Licenses { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<GroupLicense> GroupLicenses { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<GroupCourse> GroupCourses { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Learner> Learners { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have to delete the course from the DB with all of its referencing entities. For example, If the course is deleting then its properties like **AssignedCustomers**, **Licenses** etc all must be deleted.

But I don't understand one thing using Entity framework.

For deleting an entity from DB we have multiple options like.

```
Remove
RemoveRange
EntityState.Deleted
```

Sometimes Remove works but sometime RemoveRange Works and sometime Entitystate.Deleted works. Why?

My code is for deleting a **Course**

```
var courses = _context.Courses
                                              .Include("AssignedCustomers")
                                              .Include("PricingSchedule")
                                              .Include("Licenses")
                                              .Include("GroupCourses")
                                              .Include("GroupLicenses")
                                              .Where(e => courseIds.Contains(e.Id)).ToList();
                        if (courses != null && courses.Count > 0)
                        {
                            courses.ForEach(currentCourse =>
                            {

                                _context.Entry(currentCourse.PricingSchedule).State = EntityState.Deleted;
```

**Sometime remove range works and code run successfully**

```
_context.CustomerCourses.RemoveRange(currentCourse.AssignedCustomers);
```

**Below line of code gives me error but in other scenario it works why?**

```
 //currentCourse.AssignedCustomers.ToList().ForEach(ac =>
                    //{
                    //    //currentCourse.AssignedCustomers.Remove(ac);
                    //    _context.Entry(ac).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                    //});

                    _context.Entry(currentCourse).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                });
            }
            _context.SaveChanges();
```

Can anyone explain to me the difference in which situation I should use what?

The error I receive most of the time is

```
The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.
```

This error comes up when I use this piece of code

```
 currentCourse.AssignedCustomers.ToList().ForEach(ac =>
                        {

                            _context.Entry(ac).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                        });
```

**OR**

```
 currentCourse.AssignedCustomers.ToList().ForEach(ac =>
                            {

                                currentCourse.AssignedCustomers.Remove(ac):
                            });
```

after that when I hit SaveChanges The error comes up.

Comment: What exact error does it give you?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up the cascade rules in your schema and within Entity Framework so that it knows which related entities will be deleted when you go to delete a course. For instance you will want to cascade delete while others like Learner would likely have a null-able key which can be cleared if a course is removed.

Provided it is set up correctly, you should just need to use: `context.Courses.Remove(course);` and the related entities will be removed or disassociated automatically. Start with a simpler example of your parent-child relationships, one child to cascade delete, another to disassociate with a nullable FK. Your current example looks to also have many-to-many associations (GroupCourses) so depending on the mapping/relationships the approach will vary.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But the problem is I don't understand why sometime Remove works and sometimes not. Let say If you see my above class which has a proper relationship with every other entity. When I delete the main entity which is Course first I have t remove its related entities. If I use Remove method to remove an object from List it doesn't work but when I use context.CustomerCourses.RemoveRange it does work without any error. why is that? If I am using .Remove method with foreach loop is it something different than removing from context?

Comment: what's the difference between these line of codes? below approaches only first approach work seamlessly but others two are not. Why?

_context.CustomerCourses.RemoveRange(currentCourse.AssignedCustomers);

 currentCourse.AssignedCustomers.ToList().ForEach(ac =>
                            {
                                currentCourse.AssignedCustomers.Remove(ac):
                            });

 currentCourse.AssignedCustomers.ToList().ForEach(ac =>
                        {
                            _context.Entry(ac).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                        });